# dygraph: how to change fill colour and transparency level

Tags: r, time-series, visualization, dygraphs, economics

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I have been using Dygraph in R to plot diagrams, but the problem I am facing is that the plots are not solid colour but they are transparent (picture attached as dygraph of 3 stocks).

[image: dygraph of 3 stocks]

**QUESTIONS**

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I make the plots to have solid colours and not transparent?
2. How do I change the colour of the plots to a colour I want?

**CODES**

```
Economy<- cbind(SXXP, STJ, ISP)
dygraph(Economy, main = "Economic Outlook") %>%

dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE)
```

OR

```
dygraph(Economy, main = "Economic Outlook") %>%

dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 1)
```

OR

```
dygraph(Economy) %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 1, colors = c("black","red","forestgreen"))
```

**NOTE:**

1. First two codes still give a transparent diagram,
2. The third code gives solid colour with different colours, but the black one which is the highest level plot seeps into the smaller level plots and the smaller level plots only show the line,
   and I am unsure of how to fix that.
   Would appreciate your help! Thanks!

**DATASET**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("4/01/2000", "5/01/2000", "6/01/2000", 
  "7/01/2000", "10/01/2000"), SXXP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -0.00147), STJ = c(0, 
  -0.02484, 0.0995, 0.061, -0.0456), ISP = c(-0.0209, -0.002, -0.0212, 
  0.02303, -0.0172), INGA = c(-0.0274, -0.00854, -0.00689, 0.01961, 
0.00119)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> df
        Date     SXXP      STJ      ISP     INGA
1  4/01/2000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.02090 -0.02740
2  5/01/2000  0.00000 -0.02484 -0.00200 -0.00854
3  6/01/2000  0.00000  0.09950 -0.02120 -0.00689
4  7/01/2000  0.00000  0.06100  0.02303  0.01961
5 10/01/2000 -0.00147 -0.04560 -0.01720  0.00119
```

Comment: The manual says "fill will be as dark as the line of the series itself", so I'm wondering if you need to make the line darker.
`dygraph(Economy, main = "Economic Outlook") %>%
  dySeries("SXXP", color = "darkblue") %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 1)`

Comment: I tried like this based on your suggestion, 
dygraph(Economy) %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 1, colors = c("black","maroon","forestgreen")) but the black colour seeps into the other 2 plots and the other 2 plots only show the line and they dont fill in with maroon or forest green.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue with transparency; I'm guessing it has to do with your data, though. Your sample data is not representative of anything plotted (you only plotted positive values). However, I think what you're looking for is a _stacked_ area chart. Add the argument `stackedGraph = T` to `dyOptions()`.